# Core Data wants my predicate argument to be an NSNumber and an NSDate

Tags: ios, core-data, subquery, nsdate, predicate

I have a model with Events that have multiple UpcomingDates, each of which has a property date of type (NS)Date. I'm building a fetch request to only retrieve events that have upcoming dates between two given dates. The problem is, no matter how I format the input dates in my predicate I get an exception. It seems like Core Data wants my predicate arguments to be both NSDates and NSNumbers.

When I pass in NSNumbers, by doing @([date timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]), I see this:

```
predicate: 0 != SUBQUERY(upcomingDates, $upcomingDate, $upcomingDate.date >= 387270000 AND $upcomingDate.date <= 387356400).@count
-[__NSCFNumber timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x865a0b0
```

When I go the intuitive route, with plain old NSDates, I see this:

```
predicate: 0 != SUBQUERY(upcomingDates, $upcomingDate, $upcomingDate.date >= CAST(387270000.000000, "NSDate") AND $upcomingDate.date <= CAST(387356400.000000, "NSDate")).@count
-[__NSDate objCType]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x86c6450
```

Printing out the object receiving the unrecognized selector, it's always the first of the predicate arguments.

I've verified to the best of my ability that upcomingDate.date is in fact an NSDate (that's what the model specifies, but I also took a look at what was passed in when they're created). I've tried using every permutation of CASTs to NSDates and NSNumbers. I've broken the predicate down to the simplest case possible, which really just means removing one of the ANDed subquery predicates. I'm stumped.

ETA:
The predicates are as follows.
NSNumbers:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"0 != (SUBQUERY(upcomingDates, $upcomingDate, ($upcomingDate.date >= %@) AND ($upcomingDate.date <= %@))).@count", @([self.timeFilterRange[0] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]), @([self.timeFilterRange[1] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate])]
```

NSDates:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"0 != (SUBQUERY(upcomingDates, $upcomingDate, ($upcomingDate.date >= %@) AND ($upcomingDate.date <= %@))).@count", self.timeFilterRange[0] , self.timeFilterRange[1] ]
```

Comment: Any way you can give us (obfuscated versions of) the predicates?

Comment: Sure, they're pretty much what you'd expect. Added to the post.

Comment: Can you guarantee the types of the objects in `timeFilterRange`?

Comment: Yup, I'm making them myself. (lldb) po self.timeFilterRange[0]
$1 = 0x08603950 2013-04-10 07:00:00 +0000
(lldb) po [self.timeFilterRange[0] class]
$2 = 0x0248accc __NSDate

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. The NSDate version works for me without problems, with exactly your SUBQUERY.

Comment: Thanks for trying it, @MartinR. Now I'm thinking something less esoteric / more dumb, like maybe I'm accessing the same MOC on multiple threads or something…

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly, it seems the subquery was the problem. When I use this new predicate, I may or may not be getting correct results (my setup is such that it's difficult to test right now), but I am at least not getting crashes.

```
NSArray *times = @[@([self.timeFilterRange[0] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]),
                       @([self.timeFilterRange[1] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate])];
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY upcomingDates.date BETWEEN %@", times]
```